# How to specify ReplyTo EndpointReference in a JAX-WS client?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, ws-addressing

I want to use JAX-WS API to create a WS-Addressing enabled web service client. I used wsimport to create the client stub from the WSDL file, and can enable/disable WS-Addressing by using the AddressingFeature, e.g.

```
Hello hello = service.getHelloSoap11(new AddressingFeature(true, true));
```

However, I cannot find any samples in web that customize the WS-Addressing ReplyTo/FaultTo endpoint reference. Basically I want to create a WS request like the following (see the **wsa:ReplyTo** element):

```
<soapenv:Envelope ...>
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <wsa:To soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">http://localhost:8080/poc/helloService/
    </wsa:To>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://mycompany.com/poc/reply</wsa:Address>
      <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        <field1 xmlns="http://mycompany.com/poc/cust">some value1</field1>
        <field2 xmlns="http://mycompany.com/poc/cust">some value2</field2>
      </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:Action>http://mycompany.com/poc/sayHello</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:7849b04f-c74e-4836-99e4-8e25d2700fae
    </wsa:MessageID>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    ...
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I can add endpoint reference if using Spring Web Service client. However, I need to do it using JAX-WS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question.

It seems that the standard JAX-WS API does not provide a convenient way to customize the WS-Addressing From/ReplyTo/FaultTo endpoint references. However, each JAX-WS runtime may provide additional proprietary API to set the headers.

For example, the IBM JAX-WS RI provides an **EndpointReferenceManager** SPI to create the endpoint reference:

```
    import com.ibm.wsspi.wsaddressing.EndpointReference;
    import com.ibm.wsspi.wsaddressing.EndpointReferenceManager;
    import com.ibm.wsspi.wsaddressing.WSAConstants;

    public void testWSAddressing () {

    // get the port
    Hello hello = service.getHelloSoap11();

    // build a EndpiontReference of <wsa:ReplyTo>
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) hello;
    EndpointReference epr = EndpointReferenceManager.createEndpointReference(new URI(
       "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous"));
    epr.setReferenceParameter(new QName("http://mycompany.com/test", "someRefParam"),
                "12345678");

    ((BindingProvider) hello).getRequestContext()
            .put(WSAConstants.WSADDRESSING_REPLYTO_EPR, epr);
    ...

    HelloResponse response = hello.hello(request);
    }
```

The above code, when running inside IBM Websphere, will produce a SOAP message like the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <wsa:To>http://localhost:8080/poc/helloService/</wsa:To>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous
      </wsa:Address>
      <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        <someRefParam xmlns="http://mycompany.com/test">12345678</someRefParam>
      </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:BE9E173A35BAB51CB31338454394298
    </wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:Action>http://mycompany.com/Hello</wsa:Action>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    ...
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope >
```

Comment: Tommy, Similar issue i face in jboss. I have asked the question here. Can you try to help me there? please   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148111/ws-adresssing-not-working-in-jboss-5-webservice-client

Comment: I wonder how someone can someone read the received `replyTo` from the webService endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to do this with standard JAX-WS.
When getting a port, use both AddressingFeature and OneWayFeature.

```
AddressingFeature addressingfeature = new AddressingFeature();
OneWayFeature onewayfeature = new OneWayFeature(true, new WSEndpointReference(YOUR_REPLY_TO_ADDRESS, AddressingVersion.W3C));

// get the port
Hello hello = service.getHelloSoap11(addressingfeature, onewayfeature);
```

This will produce messages with "ReplyTo" tag.
You may have to grab "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt" dependency for this.